# Whose ToString() would be called?

Tags: .net, boxing

As we know, `int` has `ToString()` method which override the `ToString()` method of base type `Object`.

For this following code,

```
int x = 100;
object y = (object)x;
Console.Write(y.ToString());
```

(1) Whose `ToString()` would be called? int or object?  WHY?
(2) How we can check/view the truth? By any debug/tool?

Comment: Just check whether tostring is declared as virtual or not in object. What you are asking is the very definition of virtual functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the value is boxed, all the compiler knows about is `object`, so it is a regular virtual call to `object.ToString()`, which will then pick up the overridden `ToString()` of the struct. So: it is `object.ToString()` that is **invoked**, and the `Int32.ToString()` override ***which is executed***.

```
private static void Main()
{
    int x = 100;
    object y = (object)x;
    Console.Write(y.ToString());
}
```

becomes (comments mine):

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 x,
        [1] object y)

    // int x = 100;
    L_0000: ldc.i4.s 100
    L_0002: stloc.0

    // object y = (object)x; 
    L_0003: ldloc.0 
    L_0004: box int32
    L_0009: stloc.1

    // Console.Write(y.ToString());
    L_000a: ldloc.1 
    L_000b: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    L_0010: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
    L_0015: ret 
}
```

The important line is at `L_000b`; a regular virtual-call to `object.ToString()`.

What gets more interesting is *non-boxed* value-types; if a value-type is **known** to have a `ToString()`, then it can emit a static call:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int x = 100;
    Console.Write(x.ToString());
}

.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 x)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.s 100
    L_0002: stloc.0 
    L_0003: ldloca.s x
    L_0005: call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
    L_000a: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
    L_000f: ret 
}
```

See the static-call (`call`) at `L_0005`. **HOWEVER**, in most value-type cases it will use a *constrained* call, which will be interpreted by the JIT as a static-call if it *is* overridden, and a virtual-call if it *isn't*:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var x = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(123, "abc");
    Console.Write(x.ToString());
}
```

becomes:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<int32, string> x)
    L_0000: ldloca.s x
    L_0002: ldc.i4.s 0x7b
    L_0004: ldstr "abc"
    L_0009: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<int32, string>::.ctor(!0, !1)
    L_000e: ldloca.s x
    L_0010: constrained [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<int32, string>
    L_0016: callvirt instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()
    L_001b: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
    L_0020: ret 
}
```

The "constrained" / "callvirt" pair at `L_0010` and `L_0016` *together* make this construct, so it might not *actually* be a virtual call. The JIT / runtime can do other voodoo on it. This is [discussed more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained.aspx).

Note that a regular `class` will **always** use virtual call for this, except for the scenario `return base.ToString();`, which is a static-call to the base-types implementation.

Comment: So: it is object.ToString() that is invoked, and the Int32.ToString override which is executed. -----------------------------------------------------------So, we can say, the answer for my question is: Int32's ToString() is called ??? (2) **What does you mean "invoked"/"executed", are you talking about the underlying methodology of the design&implementation of inheritence???**

Comment: @user1033098 yes, I'm talking about the nature of polymorphism. There is a split between *what is requested* (the base-type call) and *what actually happens* (the most-overridden call).

Comment: Say... a regular simple polymorphism sample.. i have a base class A, a derived class B from A. In B, there is an override method M(). 'A a = new B(); a.M();' What happend? Also always need A.M() "invoked"???? Can you explain a bit more about "invoked"?

Comment: @user1033098 the *compiler* refers to `A.M()`, via virtual-call. At runtime, the method-table data for `B` (as the instance-type) is substituted during the call, so `B.M()` is *executed*. Just polymorphism, really.

Answer (score 4):

`Int32.ToString()` would be called, because `ToString()` is called virtually. 
`Int32.ToString()` overrides `Object.ToString()`, so at runtime it effectively replaces `Object.ToString()`.
And at runtime, `y` is a boxed `int`.

Comment: @Erno I think it is. At least the output `100` that the above snippet produces suggests it.

Comment: @Erno once boxed, it *is* a virtual call

Answer (score 2):

Int32, because that's the actual object underneath satisfying the same contract. You can check by watching the output. If this wouldn't be the case you would have "System.Object" returned instead.

Comment: But after we boxing an Int32 to object, we get another object whose GetType() is "System.Int32". So that's the reason???

Comment: @user1033098 `GetType()` will return "System.Int32" even without boxing. It returns you the type of the variable at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

**Thought that was java. Sorry!** :)
int is a primitive type.
All primitive types, are the only exceptions where the magic of OO stops.
They dont inherit object, they are not objects!(no toString method, no methods in general)

Integer, has the toString method.
If your example was with Integer, instead of int, and your object was casted to a class(like you did in your example), if that class overrides toString(eg was your custom class), or just already had toString method(like Integer class), that class toString method should be called.

Otherwise, the toString  method of the class who inherited from should be called.
If didnt inherited from nobody(means: inherited from Object class), object class toString should be called.

Writing a simple program with some prints can help you:

```
Integer x = new Integer(3);
```

print:

```
x.toString()
((Object) x).toString();
```

And new anonymous class, same as Integer, but toString Overriden

```
Integer y = new Integer(3){
    @Override
    String toString(){
    return "WHATEVER!!";

    }
    };
```

print:

```
y.toString();
```

Comment: Actually, int/Int32 inherit from object via System.ValueType. I guess you're thinking of java, where there is a difference between int and Integer. In .NET, int and System.Int32 are the same and they are full .NET Types (boxing is done by casting to object).

Comment: Indeed! thanks Botz. Thats very close to Java! :) Only changed thing was ToString, T was capital!

Comment: @Pashalis What i meant to say is that there are no primitive types in .NET/C#. This question is not about java. In .NET, every type, even int, derives from object. And there are no wrapper types for primitive types, since there are no primitive types. So the first two lines are not correct :)

Comment: @Botz3000, i understood you. You are right! What i wanted to say in my previous comment is that i got confused because i saw only title, and body of question, without seeing the tags! And i answered!! Just curious: other lines are correct in C#?

Comment: Ah, i see :) Yes, except that you can't derive from Int32 in .NET, as you are doing with the anonymous class, because Int32 derives from ValueType and all types deriving from ValueType are sealed (not inheritable). And the override annotation is not used, instead it would be `public override string ToString()`.